# How to get variable length array

Tags: c++, c++11

I know variable length arrays are not allowed in c++. My code is currently as follows:

```
int main(){
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  double h[t];
}
```

How can I create an array with length t then?

Edit: the assignment only allows char, bool, int and double. Vector isn't allowed. When I tried to compile it, it says ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'h'.

Comment: Use `std::vector<double> h(t);`. (And, don't forget to `#include <vector>` before.)

Comment: I'm sure searching could've revealed this.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It does create an array with length t.

Comment: Any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should cover this.

Comment: g++ will allow this with the right compile options. It is not standard C++, though.

Comment: If you can't use `vector`, then search about `new[]`.

Comment: An alternative would be to use `double *h = new double[t];`. (A proper program should `delete[] h;` after you don't need `h` anymore.)

Comment: And to be tidy, use `delete [] h;` when you're done.

Comment: ***it says ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'h'*** This is correct. VLAs are not part of standard c++. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: @WaisKamal To quote from the question _"variable length arrays are not allowed in c++"_. That's wrong, it's non-standard C++.

Comment: `new double[t]` how about that. You can use a smart pointer for extra kicks.

Comment: ...and you may send your teacher the following link: [Kate Gregory: Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)... ;-)